# Turn off framebuffer console in Ubuntu Minimal

Tags: linux, framebuffer

I'm trying to set up a VM based on Ubuntu Minimal to test out working with the framebuffer/DirectFB. I want the VM to only display what I put on the framebuffer, while I'm controlling the VM over SSH. So ideally, it boots to a blank screen without a console.

I enabled the framebuffer device by adding video=vesafb and vga=0x305 to the kernel parameters. The framebuffer is working, because "cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0" (over ssh) fills the screen with noise.

However, the VM still shows console 1/tty1, and even after I fill the framebuffer with data, there is still a blinking cursor.

How do I turn off the framebuffer console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add console=/dev/null as a kernel parameter, it should help.